# What happens with extra spaces and newlines in C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a difference between;

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

and

```
int main(){
return
0;
}
```

They will all likely compile to same executable. How does the C/C++ compiler treat the extra spaces and newlines, and if there is a difference between how newlines are treated differently than spaces in C code?

Also, how about tabs? What's the significance of using tabs instead of spaces in code, if there is any?

Comment: "They will all likely compile to same executable" ==> "They ***will*** all compile to same executable." Whitespace is ignored except where the code is required to be on one line, or to disambiguate, or it is part of a string literal. A tab character is whitespace.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that, just like spaces and Newsline, both (1) comments and (2) variable names, also do not make it into the executable - so do use then and make them readable !

Comment: The compiler treats them pretty much the same as you do when you read them, except it doesn't get confused by strange layouts like people do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any sequence of 1+ whitespace symbol (space/line-break/tab/...) is equivalent to a single space.

Exceptions:

- Whitespace is preserved in string literals. They can't contain line-breaks, except C++ raw literals (`R"(...)"`). The same applies to file names in `#include`.
- Single-line comments (`//`) are terminated with line-breaks only.
- Preprocessor directives (starting with `#`) are terminated with line-breaks only.
- `\` followed by a line-break removes both, allowing multi-line `//` comments, preprocessor directrives, and string literals.

Also, whitespace symbols are ignored if there is punctuation (anything except letters, numbers, and `_`) to the left and/or to the right of it. E.g. `1 + 2` and `1+2` are the same, but `return a;` and `returna;` are not.

Exceptions:

- Whitespace is not ignored inside string literals, obviously. Nor in `#include` file names.
- Operators consisting of >1 punctuation symbols can't be separated, e.g. `cout < < 1` is illegal. The same applies to things like `//` and `/*` `*/`.
- A space between punctuation might be necessary to prevent it from coalescing into a single operator. Examples:

  - `+ +a` is different from `++a`.
  - `a+++b` is equivalent to `a++ +b`, but not to `a+ ++b`.
  - Pre-C++11, closing two template argument lists in a row required a space: `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.
- When defining a function-like macro, the space is not allowed before the opening parenthesis (adding it turns it into an object-like macro). E.g. `#define A()` replaces `A()` with nothing, but `#define A ()` replaces `A` with `()`.